# In Php 401 & boolean true return true always

Tags: php

I am running this code in my php code. But always its return true.
Please describe this code.

```
<?php
    $statusCode = 401;
    $statusValue = true;
    var_dump($statusCode == $statusValue);
?>
```

Comment: If you want to test the type too use `===` instead like : `$statusCode === $statusValue`

Comment: 401 is a number that is converted to true (because it's not 0) and `true` is `true` so the dynamic cast of the 401 gives true and true is equal to true :)

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php